# Typescript mapping of key to values as a function for events

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a map with key beings type of events and value a callback with the payload of the events. But I'm not able to make the callback receive the argument of the proper event

```
type DeviceEvent<T extends string, Data> = {
  type: T;
  data: Data;
}

type EventA = DeviceEvent<"event_a", {some: string}>
type EventB = DeviceEvent<"event_b", {some_other: string}>
type EventC = DeviceEvent<"event_c", {some_else: number}>
type EventD = DeviceEvent<"event_d", {some_elseNumber: number}>


type EventImInterestedIn = EventA | EventB | EventC

const test: Record<Partial<EventImInterestedIn["type"]>, (data: EventImInterestedIn["data"]) => void> = {
    event_a: ({some}) => {},
    event_b: ({some_other}) => {}
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBuBLAxhAovCA7YAeAKlBAB7DYAmAzlJcAE6JYDmANLAIbDsB8UAvFADeAKChRQkAFxR8AblFRyndtJjL5AX2HCJ0DNmABBfrAQp0mHLgBECAwH121toMoB7ALYRptBsw3cOuB6lsAAQiZwSKj6Vrah9gBGzkLuXvZuwAAWEHQ%209IxMAUGQULHAAMKRZjGhNnY49sgprp4Q9hAANpTeUFgArh6JucW6ZaEw1dEWBvUJ5C1p7V09AHKDw3l9GyOB2mPlAJIehzi5ELQQ5Kcm5cYAPuMGEY-lFdrIbli04hfA0gAlCCfOjkXAABXYdGAiHYnVwRxOZzofyupwA2tZdNYALrcNgACiUXGkiNOZBRl2uWExxKcOIAlPxePA3IhyLwBCIxGIGsBHNICa0vBomXxeIINCwFLyEolBcL2pkcnRRcyhFoNEA)

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a record you lose the connection between the `type` key and its `data`, so the type of the `data` argument in each callback property will be a union of all `data` fields instead of the one corresponding to that `type`.

You can avoid this problem by declaring a mapped type like this:

```
type Events = {
  [E in EventImInterestedIn as E['type']]?: (data: E['data']) => void
}
```

It maps over the `EventImInterestedIn` union members, and uses each `type` property as a key (using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) with `as`) and the appropriate `data` property as the parameter for the callback.

If you use `Events` as the type for `test`, the correct callback parameter types will be inferred:

```
const test: Events = {
    event_a: ({some}) => {},
    // (parameter) some: string
    event_b: ({some_other}) => {},
    // (parameter) some_other: string
    event_c: (e) => {}
    // (parameter) e: { some_else: number; }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyoebN)